# How to post to MVC form using BeginForm without reloading the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a contact form which when submitted sends email message. I have an action method `Send` that handles sending of the emails. The client wants to have a modal appear after the successful execution of `Send` method, but without any reloading of the current view. Whatever I did, I always have the page reload after `Send` is executed.

I thought of having onClick event so when the form is submitted I call a JS function which then tells the controler to send an email and upon success the modal is shown. The thing is I have to use BeginForm so that I take advantage of DataAnnotations so I can validate the form, but in that case the page reloads on every submit, I couldn't prevent that. Also I have no idea how to pass the model to the JS function.
How to get that email sent and success value passed back to the page without reloading the view?

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "Contact", FormMethod.Post))
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label for="first-name" class="form-label">*First Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label for="last-name" class="form-label">*Last Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label for="message" class="form-label">*Message</label>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
                    </div>

                    <input id="btnbtn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

As I was suggested using ajax, I tried, but I can't get the model into JS code, it has null values:

```
var url = '/Home/Send';
        $(function () {
            $("#btnbtn").click(function () {
                var myModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
                console.log(myModel);
            });
            });
```

It just picked up the values from a dropdown list (reason for contacting):

`{FirstName: null, LastName: null, EmailAddress: null, …}
ContactReasons: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
FirstName: null
LastName: null
Message: null`

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/25277570/5523033

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax call if you don't want to reload/refresh the page.